# Unable to edit menu in Neto

Tags: neto

I want to edit menu item in `Neto` but could not reach the right template. My current theme is `midsummer` and I am editing suggested template `header/template.html` (Please check attached screen shot) but I can`t see any changes at front end. I don`t know why ?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a inbuilt potion for refreshing `cache` in Neto, I clicked on that and now I can get the result.

Comment: How to reach this template page. I am not able to see this template tree view